# Passing value from Firebase from one tableView to another

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to pass value I get from **Firebase** to another `tableView`. I get 2 values from **Firebase** - "Brands" and "Products". I am trying to make like car app. If you click on Ford then new `tableView` will appear and shows all the Ford models. This is what I've done so far.

like this I get Brands from **Firebase**:

```
func parseSnusBrands(){
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").child("Brands")

    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            if let all = (snapshot.value?.allKeys)! as? [String]{
                for a in all{
                    if let products = snapshot.value![a] as? [[String:String]]{
                        self.snusBrandsArray.append(["key":a,"value":products])
                    }
                }
                self.snusBrandsTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

And like this I detect which cell is clicked and print the product that belongs to the clicked Brand:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    print("products at \(indexPath.row)  --> \(snusBrandsArray[indexPath.row]["value"])")

}
```

How to pass the `(snusBrandsArray[indexPath.row]["value"])` to new `tableView`? I tried using segues and looking for tutorials like "How to pas value between viewControllers" but I am out of luck. Right now I have 2 `tableViewController.swift` files and one `tableViewCustomCell.swift` file. Do I need some more files?

Comment: read about the prepareforSegue if this tableviews are in different controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For send data, first of all declare your variable in 2nd view controller..

```
  var productsValue = [[String:String]]()
```

and in 1st viewcontroller

```
  var valueTopass = [[String:String]]()
```

Than in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, take a value in one valueTopass

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("products at \(indexPath.row)  --> \(snusBrandsArray[indexPath.row]["value"])")
    if let products = snusBrandsArray[indexPath.row]["value"] as? [[String:String]]{
        valueTopass = products
        performSegueWithIdentifier("toProducts", sender: self)
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if (segue.identifier == "toProducts") {
        var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SnusProductsTableViewController
        viewController.productsValue = valueTopass
        print(productValues)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! I have one question

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Segues to pass the data forward.

To pass data from the current view controller to the next new view controller using segues, first create a segue with an identifier in the relevant storyboard. Override your current view controller's `prepareForSegue` method. Inside the method check for the segue you just created by its identifier. Cast the destination view controller and pass data to it by setting properties on the downcast view controller.

Setting an identifier for a segue:

[image]

Segues can be performed programatically or using button action event set in the storyboard by ctrl+drag to destination view controller.
You can call for a segue programatically, when needed, using segue identifier in the view controller:

```
func showDetail() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailingSegue", sender: self)
}
```

You can configure segue payload in the override version of `prepareForSegue` method. You can set required properties before destination view controller is loaded.

**Swift**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetailingSegue" {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        controller.isDetailingEnabled = true
    }
}
```

`DetailViewController` is the name of the second view controller and `isDetailingEnabled` is a public variable in that view controller.

To expand on this pattern, you can treat a public method on `DetailViewController` as a pseudo initializer, to help initialize any required variables. This will self document variables that need to be set on `DetailViewController` without having to read through it's source code. It's also a handy place to put defaults.

**Swift**

```
func initVC(isDetailingEnabled: Bool) {
    self.isDetailingEnabled = isDetailingEnabled
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the whole dictionary with all the contents from firebase to the new VC using prepare for segue? 
And then store the dict in the destinationVC data model?

That should do the trick.